# How to capture Alert message using jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I just tried to capture Alert messages from application using Java ,but i couldn't able to capture using jmeter
i.e
Whenever I created any record in application ,it shows an alert message as "50.6.78.42.32 says N12345 record created successfully "
I need to capture this alert message .could any one please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about [JavaScript Alert](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_alert.asp) it cannot be "captured", as per JMeter Project main page:

> JMeter is not a browser, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. **In particular, JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages**. Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).

So if you're running your test using [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler the alert won't be there. The options are in:

- Inspect your page source code using your browser developer tools, find the function which generates the alert and write the equivalent code using [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)
- Switch to [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/) which provides JMeter integration with [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) browser automation framework, this way you will run your test using a real browser with the access to Alerts.